# Cinematography: Should we make this on topic?

Tags: discussion

I've had the thought for a while, and now I've seen a similar question on the site and decided to ask here. Should we open this group to include cinematography? This would not include anything to do with acting, but would cover anything to do with the background, lighting, camera angles, etc. What do you guys think?

Comment: Are you referring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinematography ? If so can you edit your question?

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks, I really need to learn to spell...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I ask Videography related questions?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/28/can-i-ask-videography-related-questions)

Answer (score 14):

There's actually a video and film production stack currently in proposal over at Are51 **(and we could definitely use participants if you're interested in that sort of thing!)**:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2797/video-and-film-production

I think the two topics (photography and cinematography) are broad enough and different enough that it probably makes more sense to keep them separate so as to not dilute the focus of the Photography stack *or* the film stack.

My .02 cents worth on the subject...

**EDIT 5.18.2011:** TBH, when I wrote this I expected video-SE to be farther along in the process than it is. Unfortunately it hasn't really moved much since I originally wrote this. Since we *are* getting more video questions now than we were in February when this question was first raised and video-SE seems no closer to being available to fill the role I think it probably makes sense to take on a limited scope of video questions... Specifically ones related to the dSLR hardware as a video platform. As @jrista observed [in chat earlier today](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1001444#1001444):

> "Regarding video related stuff...I think the line should be drawn at what is capable with existing still photography HARDWARE. If someone who is a photographer has a question about how to use the video features of their fancy new DSLR, I don't think we should be turning them away. If someone has a question about how to focus while recording video with their fancy new DSLR, I don't think we should turn them away. If someone starts asking how to compose some green-screen clips with CG, that is definitely off topic."

I'd have to agree with that assessment, with the caveat that I'd want to revisit the topic when and if the video-SE gets going and we have someplace we can migrate these sorts of questions to...

Comment: That proposal looks like it has a ways to go... for now I suggest allowing them, tagging them, and then when that site graduates to beta, moving them over.

Comment: @cabbey I'd say if we do allow video, we should limit it to the moving-picture side of things. Audio stuff might fit better at http://audio.stackexchange.com/. Unfortunately (or fortunately, for the video SE proposal), this wouldn't leave any room for questions like "How do I sync my audio and video tracks?"

Comment: On the edit: I voted to close http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12256/record-videos-directly-to-the-computer, but I'm surprised so many other people did too, since it fits under the first part of jrista's statement....

Comment: I am kind of surprised about the topic matt linked as well. I feel a though that falls within the mostly on-topic pool, as it was directly related to DSLR hardware and Canon tethering capabilities. Long term, it might be serviced better by migration to Video-SE, but until that site gets going...I feel we should keep it open.

Comment: Hmmm... My initial take was that the question was more about the computer equipment than the camera equipment which informed my decision to vote for a close... *But* upon a second read through I think I scanned the question and arrived at that conclusion too quickly as when I reread it I tend to agree with @mattdm and @jrista's conclusion. Bottom line: I'd support a reopen unless someone else can offer up a compelling take on why it should stay closed...

Answer (score 7):

The Audio stack exchange site just became the [Audio-Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/) site. This seems like a better place for cinematography questions to go.